# $\int_0^{\infty} \sin (a^2 x^2)dx$ picking the contour of integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I just have a question about what contour I should pick for this problem $$\int_0^{\infty} \sin (a^2 x^2)dx$$ for positive a.

I used the freshnel integral for $\int_0^{\infty} \sin (x^2)dx$ with an angle of $\pi/4$. (See below)

My question is, would the angle that I would use change because of the $a^2$ addition to the problem or would I want to use the same contour and just carry the $a^2$ through the problem?

Or perhaps there is a way to take care of it right off the bat?
For example of what I mean, see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850221/contour-integration-of-int-0-infty-frac-sinaxx).

Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: Please don't put "question" in the title. Imagine what the front page would look like if everybody did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $u=ax$:

$$
\int_0^\infty\sin\left(a^2x^2\right)\mathrm dx=\frac1a\int_0^\infty\sin\left(a^2x^2\right)\mathrm d(ax)=\frac1a\int_0^\infty\sin u^2\mathrm du\;.
$$

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you :)